# Vector of class within a class, how to restrict it for only 1 time?

Tags: c++, class

I have a:

```
class galaxy
{
private:
    std::string type;
    double mass;
    std::vector<galaxy> satellites;
public: 
//things here
};
```

So a galaxy can have satellites which are themselves galaxies. But if I do it this way then satellites would have satellites themselves.

Do I have to create another class exactly with the same properties except the vector of galaxies? Or is there another better approach?

Comment: A more practical option might be: just don't give satellites satellites. Is there a problem with them having an empty satellites vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't satellites have satellites? An almost recursive pattern of orbiting bodies is how our entire universe works!

But, putting that aside.

If, in *your* concept, not every galaxy can have satellites, then a list of satellites shouldn't be part of `galaxy`.

Why not bring this logic out of the class?

```
class galaxy
{
private:
    std::string type;
    double mass;
public: 
//things here
};

std::map<galaxy, std::vector<galaxy>> galaxiesWithSatellites;
```

This map would replace whatever structure you're currently using to store your galaxies. Now there's only *one* galaxy->satellite mapping in the whole application.

Note that I'm not necessarily suggesting it *has* to be a `map`; that brings with it its own complexities (e.g. your galaxies would need to be less-than comparable); you could instead give each galaxy its own unique ID, then have a `std::map<GalaxyId, std::vector<galaxy>>`.

But I'll leave you to figure out the details: the point is that this container probably shouldn't be in your class.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Composite Design Pattern  in your situation. We define two sepated calsses Satellite and Galaxy. But only Galaxy has containers (vector) of Satellite.

Here is my sample solution:

```
class Component
{
protected:
  std::string type;
  double mass;
public:
    virtual void traverse() = 0;
};

class Satellite: public Component
{
  public:
    void traverse() override 
    {

    }
};

class Galaxy: public Component
{
private:
    vector < Component* > satellites;
public:
    void add(Component* item)
    {
        satellites.push_back(item);
    }
    void traverse() override 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++)
          satellites[i]->traverse();
    }
};
```